# Css input:focus only on first click

Tags: css, input, focus

Does anybody know a way to input:focus an element only on first click?

```
<style>
input[type='text'].error:focus{border-color:#f00} 
</style>
```

So, if the user "focus out" it returns to the original border color.

Thanks in advance for any hint.

**Edit**

I wasn't sure at all. Thanks @blender.

I think the easist way to do it is using jquery or similar, right?

Comment: If I'm reading the question correctly, not with CSS, no.

Comment: If user clicks on the element again, should it change the border, or it stays the same?

Comment: The element should return to the original border color on "focus out", but when the user :focus another time on the element it should be the default :focus color. Hope i was clear ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all who have the same or a similar question, here's is a possible jQuery solution:

```
 $('input').on('focusout',function(){
 $(this).removeClass('error');
 });
```

This will remove the error class on :focus out.
When the user :focusin another time the input element, it will return to the default color.

Example default border-color with css:

```
 <style>
  input[type='text']:focus {border-color: black;}
 </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am confused as to what you mean by "only on first click". If you want to style an input on click, you can just use this CSS:

```
input[type="text"].error:focus { border-color: #f00; }
```

And this HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="error" />
```

That will style the input border given it has the class of error (if you are adding/removing the class dynamically that is).

However, if you are styling for errors (like if the user hasn't filled out the form), you might want to try something like this:

```
 input[type="text"]:invalid { border-color: #f00; }

 input[type="text"]:valid{ border-color: #; } //If form is filled in
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<input type="text" required />
```

Does that help answer your question a little bit?

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the validation is already done by php with an if-else statement. Also: input:valid doesn't work in older browsers like IE8

Comment: I read your comment above about how you want the styling to be different the second time you click the input... I don't think I have the knowledge to help you with that, I'm sorry.

However, if you would like to use HTML5 form validation and have it work in older browsers, I suggest checking out Modernizr ([http://modernizr.com/](http://modernizr.com/)) or h5Validate ([http://ericleads.com/h5validate/](http://ericleads.com/h5validate/)). Both are great plugins that will enable the feature for a myriad of browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As @Blender said, it does not seem possible in pure CSS. 
I would suggest to handle `focusin` and `focusout` events to add a class to an element and use `data-` attributes to get if element was already clicked or not. 
Have a look at this [jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/cEYN6/)